# To tell me who I am, you must have made me cry

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

They paid to see it and they applauded, as this concept was very new.

But only I could relate, for the differences in our **case**s were very few.

This made me sad and I chose to cry.

It’s the only time they care, so I no more try.

That’s how it has been since my birth,

So is the case of my brothers on Earth.

It’s in our genes, they say. I can’t question even if I may.

They push us to the end of life, whenever they want.

Some have unavoidable reasons but mostly just chat.

Who am I, or what am I, please solve this riddle,

the riddler can’t rhyme anymore, so middle middle middle.

**HINT #1:**

> Definitely you have seen it/him/her (may be in real, in media or in picture)

**HINT #2:**

> The words "brothers", "end of life" are only figurative.

**HINT #3:**

> This hint might not help one get close to the answer but once someone got the answer, this hint can reason with one of the above lines. Hint is: **Movie Reference in one of these lines.**

**HINT #4:**

> The word that has been highlighted is itself a hint. "**case**"

**HINT #5:**

> The word mentioned in Hint 4 is related to Hint 3. Now you know which particular line is referring to a movie. And you got the word "case" to think of the movie.

This is my first attempt here. I will accept the answer if one can explain all the lines. If there are any English issues please do let me know. Good luck.

Comment: Is the movie "The Truman show"?

Comment: @MarkN No, that's not it. I believe that my reasoning applied to every line of the riddle is logical indeed. You guys will be final judge of how good the question was once the answer is out. I do not know how you thought of "Truman Show" so I can not comment on whether you are on right track or not.

Comment: Should I give away the answer?

Comment: can you add any hints? it's been several months

Comment: @question_asker I had been checking to see if people had replied to my responses in comments. Hint: The Line 1 is talking about some movie and name of the movie is "Curious CASE of Benjamin Button". People paid to watch the movie, the movie was a hit and the concept (story) was unique. The answer of the riddle can relate itself to the story of Benjamin Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER**

The movie reference from the word 'case' is: The curious case of Benjamin Button.
Key-theme of the movie is backward-aging - starting old (tall) and turning younger (shorter) as time passes by.

> They paid to see it and they applauded, as this concept was very new. But only I could relate, for the differences in our cases were very few

The answer to the riddle is connecting to movie's protagonist and saying while audience applauded the storyline, it instead sympathized because it also grows backwards during its course of life.

> This made me sad and I chose to cry. It’s the only time they care, so I no more try

indicates that the utility of this object is only when it cries - sheds a tear - melts.

> That’s how it has been since my birth, So is the case of my brothers on Earth.

tells that this melting characteristic of the object is not unique to a specific kind but is a common trait among every kind of this object.

> It’s in our genes, they say. I can’t question even if I may

indicates that melting is sole purpose of its existence so there is no utility without it

> They push us to the end of life, whenever they want. Some have unavoidable reasons but mostly just chat

"They" implies people here who intentionally push it to the end of life by somehow forcing it to melt. May be by burning it? There are unavoidable reasons where you may want to burn something (like source of light) but some just want to burn it in background while they talk (like a decor)

Tying the pieces together: Humans burn it and it melts causing it to reduce in its height until eventually it no longer exist.

The answer is:

> Candles

Apologies if this turned out to be a disappointment. It is always tough to maintain the balance between not being too straightforward and also not let readers keep guessing too much

Answer (score 5):

Preliminary answer: Just to throw some ideas out there.

> They paid to see it and they applauded, as this concept was very new. 
>   But only I could relate, for the differences in our cases were very few.

Makes me think of original films, when the concept of moving pictures was new.
The case could refer to [La Case de Dreyfus à l'île du Diable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreyfus_Affair_(film_series))

> This made me sad and I chose to cry. 
>   It’s the only time they care, so I no more try.

In sticking with the movie theme, this could reference trip to the Moon, where the moon cries when the rocket lands in his eye. Same director as the Dreyfus Affair

> That’s how it has been since my birth, 
>   So is the case of my brothers on Earth.

Qualifying brothers with on Earth either means there are other brothers not on earth, or the subject is not on Earth. Or maybe just to rhyme :P But I'm sticking with Moon as an answer here.

Rest of the Poem: Still working on it (read: I'm stumped).

Comment: Good thinking, but alas, it is not getting close to the answer. To narrow down the scope of the movie part, use the fact that I am not a native English speaker and only know about movies that got famous in Hollywood.

Comment: To clarify the line, "This made me sad and I .....". "This" in this line refers to the fact that people applauded a movie but can not see that the theme of the movie is also the story of "the answer".

Comment: And about your third point regarding "Earth". It is there to rhyme. :P It means the brothers around the world.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you are

> An iPhone

They paid to see it and they applauded, as this concept was very new.
But only I could relate, for the differences in our cases were very few.

> People generally pay and applaud at the launches of the new iPhones. In terms of technology, they may be new, but their design is very similar from model to model

This made me sad and I chose to cry.
It’s the only time they care, so I no more try.

> Not sure on this section, still working it out

That’s how it has been since my birth,
So is the case of my brothers on Earth.

> All iPhones have been released in much the same way from the inception of the technology

It’s in our genes, they say. I can’t question even if I may.

They push us to the end of life, whenever they want.
Some have unavoidable reasons but mostly just chat.

> Many people will use a phone until it dies. Generally, this comes from standard usage (chatting with others) but sometimes accidents happen